# Ожидание ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем добрый день, можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы python ожидал ошибки. Например. Если python ждет цифр например пароля, а вместо цифр вписываются слова.

Comment: что значит "ожидал ошибки"? "_Например. Если python ждет цифр например пароля, а вместо цифр вписываются слова_" - то что?

Comment: читайте про try except

Comment: По заголовку я ожидал, что вопрос про юнит-тесты.